# Как получить значение валюты пользователя (EUR, USD, RUB, KZT...) используя locale и нативный JS?

Tags: javascript

Я делаю простенький конвертер валют, хочу, чтобы автоматически определялась валюта по умолчанию (EUR, USD, RUB, KZT...), для этого я нашел единственно верное решение - использовать locale, но как именно вытащить из него значение не понял, так как в свойстве currency во всех примерах устанавливают значение, а не получают. Возможно есть оптимальный вариант без использования библиотек. Пока что смог вытащить только язык используемый пользователем из window.navigator, но это мне мало что даёт.

Comment: А зачем браузеру держать курс валюты юзера в браузере? Как вариант, получать гео.позицию юзера, из базы брать валюту соответствующую позиции юзера и выводить.

Comment: Или получать язык и хранить соответствие валюты языку.

Comment: @De.Minov, не курс, а обозначение. Вообще-то оно входит в локаль, как минимум, на винде. https://i.stack.imgur.com/1b0f7.png

Answer (score 1):

Вопрос решил с помощью библиотеки https://www.npmjs.com/package/iso-country-currency

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, лучше б ты это соседнему ответу написал...

Comment: @DenisChuchos, там хардкод внутри...

Comment: @Qwertiy 1. у соседнего ответа что-то типа комментариев присутствует, с натяжкой можно их трактовать как объяснение. 2. соседний ответ не попадался мне на проверку.

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin, зато тут что-то рабочее, а там какая-то каша...

Answer (score -1):

```
var userLang = navigator.language || navigator.userLanguage; // определяем язык браузера пользователя
var USD, etc // определяем значения валют
var money = ''; // определяем контейнер для валюты 

if (userLang == ruble)  {
    money = ruble;
} else if (userLang == eng) {
    money = usd;
} // и так далее
```